# Profit Calculator in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to build a program that would calculate the profit made for four items.this is the code i have so far. Im not doing the calculation part yet, im trying to allow the user to choose what items they want to purchase and how to store those values.

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    int item=0;
    double price=0;
    String itemName="";
    String yes ="";
    String no="";
    String answer="";
    String response;    

    Scanner list=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println( "These are the current items availabe:" ); 
    System.out.println( "Item Number\t Item Name" ); 
    System.out.println( "1)\t\t Flour\n2)\t\t Juice\n3)\t\t Crix\n4)\t\t Cereal" );
    System.out.println("Enter the item number you wish to purchase");
    item=list.nextInt();

    if( item == 1 ) 
    {
        price = 25; 
        itemName = "Flour"; 
        System.out.println( "You selected Flour" ); 
    }
    else if( item == 2 ) 
    {
        price = 15; 
        itemName = "Juice"; 
        System.out.println( "You selected Juice" ); 
    }
    else if( item == 3 ) 
    {
        price = 10; 
        itemName = "Crix"; 
        System.out.println( "You selected Crix" ); 
    }
    else if( item == 4 ) 
    {
        price = 30; 
        itemName = "Cereal"; 
        System.out.println( "You selected Cereal" ); 
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println( "Invalid Item Number Entered!" ); 
    }

    return;
    System.out.println("Would you like to purchase another item?");
    Scanner answer1=new Scanner(System.in);
    response=answer1.next();

    if(answer==yes)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the item number you wish to purchase");
        item=list.nextInt();
    }
    else if(answer==no)
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you for shopping with us");
    }
```

The question is, how do i go about doing this or is my method so far accurate?

Also for the if else statements when i answer yes or no, it still asks `Enter the item number you wish to purchase` even if i input no. How do i correct this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not right, on many levels:

```
String yes=""; //this is an empty string... The name does not mean anything...

....
if(answer==yes){ //comparing something with an empty string the bad way...
```

Should be probably

```
private static final String YES="yes"; //now it has content
```

and later

```
if(answer.equals(YES)) { //proper string equalitz checking
...
```

Remember: `String`s are objects. Use `.equals()` to compare their equality.

Apply the same for the `no` part of course.

Also:

```
Scanner answer1=new Scanner(System.in);
response=answer1.next(); //you store the result into response

if(answer==yes){ //you check answer???
```

Should be:

```
Scanner answer1=new Scanner(System.in);
response=answer1.next(); //you store the result into response

if(response.equals(YES)){ //correct check
```

Comment: side question: Will the compiler in this case, replace YES with "yes"? Rather than check the variable at runtime?

Comment: The compiler should replace `YES` with "yes", yes.

Comment: @Cruncher with static final modifiers, I definitely think it should...